# What algorithm could be used to determine distribution of possible results of the rolls of multiple variable-sided dice?

Tags: probability-distributions, algorithms, dice

In a recent project, I came across a problem where we needed to provide an end user with the distribution of likelihoods that certain sums of rolls would appear.

The dice rolled would be given as a sum of dice in [standard dice notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dice_notation) (i.e. `3d6+4d8-3` - "the sum of three independent six-sided die rolls plus the sum of four independent eight-sided die rolls minus three"). However, converting this algorithmically into a distribution was immensely challenging - we still haven't found a way to go about this issue aside of calculating every possible combination (which is bad, as we sometimes have very large sets of numbers).

Is there an efficient way to determine the likelihood, or do we have to find every combination?

Comment: FFT is the fastest, if it's too fast for you, just DP in O(n^2).

Comment: You could use generating functions. A single roll `1dn` corresponds to a generating function $g_n(x)=x+x^2+x^3+\cdots+x^n$. The generating function for the sum of a combination of throws is then the product of the individual throws. So for example `3d6+4d8-3` has generating function
$$g(x)=x^{-3}g_6(x)^3 g_8(x)^4.$$
The role of the generating function is then that the coefficient of $x^k$ gives the number of ways of getting the sum of the dice to be equal to $k$. It is straightforward to turn this into a probability, but you may need a friendly CAS to get the coefficients of $g(x)$ easily.

Comment: My comment was made for the scenario of having a small set of complicated combos so that you can have a CAS spew out the generating function well in advance. This probably won't work, if you need to prepared to meet new combo throws on the fly. The calculation of the product of polynomials can be speeded up as pointed out user202729.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding the comments to an answer:

- Denote the probability, that you get sum $a$ with probability $p$, by the generating function:

$$ g(x) = \sum \left( p \times x^a \right) $$

where the sum is taken over all pairs of $(a, p)$.

For example, a regular 6-sided dice would have generating function for its distribution:

$$ \frac 1 6 (x + x^2 + ... + x^6) $$

because the probability of getting each sum from $1$ to $6$ is $\frac 1 6$.

Consider 2 functions $g_1(x)$ and $g_2(x)$ being the g.f. represent the  probability when 2 set of dices are rolled. It can be proven that the g.f. of the probability when the two sets of dices are rolled is $g_1(x)\times g_2(x)$. (the proof is quite easy, you should be able to prove this yourself)

Therefore, to calculate the distribution, you can:

- Make the g.f. for each dice.
- Multiply them all together. (use FFT or naive polynomial multiplication)
- Calculate the coefficients.

Comment: I wasn't taught any of this in school. :\ I'm not familiar with the Fast Fourier transform in any way, so I'll have to use naive polynomial multiplication (because I understand that part).

Comment: @AddisonCrump Easy to understand resource about FFT: [link](http://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/algorithms/notes/02-fft.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the help, we got [naive polynomial multiplication working](https://github.com/TrulyFree/DieHard/blob/master/app/src/main/java/io/github/trulyfree/diehard/dice/distribution/DistributionUtil.java#L19) and we'll work on FFT soon enough. :D